# Angular2 protractor element directive

Tags: angular, protractor, element, directive

I'm working in Angular2.

I would like to get an element that has a custom directive with protractor.

I have this element:

```
<span *ngIf="mobilePhoneControl.errors"
        [msg-src-key]="mobilePhoneControl.errors.loctoolKeys[0]"
        class="alert alert-warning"
        role="alert">
        Invalid Phone number.
</span>
```

I would like to get the element by searching the msg-src-key directive.

But I don't know how should I do that.

Thanks.

EDIT :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4RcR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *CSS selector*:

```
$('[\\[msg-src-key\\]*=loctoolKeys]');
```

Here we need to use `\\` to escape square brackets since they have a special meaning in CSS selector syntax, `*=` means "contains".

`$("selector")` is a shorthand for `element(by.css("selector"))`.